# Post editing: less is more?

Tags: discussion, editing

Posts benefit from being clear, and having obvious typos and other language errors fixed so they aren't distracting.  Problem posts can have downvoting or closure voting reversed with edits that make the post's value more obvious or address issues.  With posts that are highly viewed, language errors can be reading stumbling blocks for everyone who lands on the thread, so simple fixes can provide benefits for many future readers.  Appropriate tags can help attract the right people to answer a question, or make it easier for future visitors to find the information in a search.

But there's an unfortunate side effect of fixing/improving everything that would benefit from it.  The SE software lists posts on the main page in potentially several ways.

- If you filter with the Newest questions button, it lists the user name of the person who asked the question.  In that view, you never see who posted the most recent answer, or any other development on the question.
- If you filter with the Active questions button, it lists the user name of the person who most recently did anything in relation to anything in the question thread, including posting an answer or editing the question or an answer, or even editing tags.
- If you use the Home button, the view is similar to filtering with the Active questions button.

If there is no editing going on, the Active view at least lets you see who has posted a question or answer most recently on every thread.  But if there's editing, you lose that important information.

In most cases, nobody cares who edited something on a thread.  The exception might be a post with a serious problem that is attracting downvotes or closure/deletion votes.  Spotting on the main page that a trusted editor has modified the post may attract readers to revisit and reverse their voting.  Otherwise, there's a downside.

Joachim and I may have the worst cases of "OCD" as far as editing posts.  I believe the edits we make improve the posts and often solve problems that would limit the ability of the OP to get an answer, or might lead a new user to experience their question or answer as not being valued.  But looking at the main page today, I am once again struck by this:

- Setting the page display option at 15 questions, Joachim or I are the user names listed on 10 of those.
- Setting the display option at 30 questions, the two of us are the names associated with 17 of the questions.
- Setting the display at 50 questions, we are the names on 22 of them.

Granted, a few of these represent actual answer posts, but I see a problem with the main page being dominated with our names because of our content curation.  It detracts from the sense of community and degrades the usefulness of the information presented.

This is pretty basic to the SE user interface, so there's virtually no chance the displayed information could be modified.  I'm wondering whether we should fight our instincts and minimize our editing to focus on cases where it would directly affect the success of the post.  Or, at least maybe keep track of the posts with non-critical issues, and space the editing out over time when it can be buried, one at a time, among other posts.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, **there's no problem here**. The fact that 2 users "dominate" the list of active posts doesn't mean that these users "dominate" the community in any way, they are just more active than others.

Improving the quality of posts is a very important task on SE, just as important as creating good content. Not every person has the same priorities or amount of time to contribute, and correcting bad grammar often takes a lower priority than earning points...

So having a few active users improve existing posts is better than not improving anything. I'd argue that a user who never posts answers but only edits posts to improve them is just as valuable as a user who always answers questions.

Comment: I mostly agree with what you're saying, but wouldn't go as far as "there's no problem".  The author's names are part of differentiating posts in the list; there's a lot of useful information in who wrote the question or answer.  It's often part of what drives a reader to view the thread.  If everything shows the same name, you lose that information (and the author loses the sunshine).  Who did some minor editing is useless information.  And I do think theres a different community vibe seeing a large collection of contributor names vs. seeing a few names on everything.  (cont'd)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest foregoing critical edits that could make or break a post just for name variety.  But maybe there's some flexibility or timing that could apply to non-critical edits.

Comment: I raised the issue on MSE just to see what kind of reaction there would be to a request to change the UI so the author's names don't get replaced by the editor's names.  On the big sites, they have the reverse issue.  It's common to get sprees of minor editing that fill the main page.  They rely on the editor's name to know what to ignore.  :-)  But on those sites, the page turns over quickly.  With our volume, it can take weeks.